# Javascript getElementsByTagName() weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

[Connect4 - Game](http://test.tristans.tk)
I am making a connect4 game and when I return the canvas objects to an array with:

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
```

It returns the first 18 objects fine. The Chrome javascript console (console.log(canvas[id]);) prints out the html tags. but above 18 it just writes out canvas#+id.
Because of that I get errors when I click on the bottom boxes to draw a circle.

```
function create_circle(index) {

    if (start==0) {
        color = 'red';
        start++;
    } else if (start==1) {
        color = 'black';
        start--;
    } else {
        color = 'white';
    }

    var circle = document.canvas[index].getContext('2d'); // IT SHOWS THE ERROR HERE

    circle.beginPath();
    circle.arc(40, 40, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    circle.fillStyle = color;
    circle.fill();
}
```

Comment: It should be `document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')`, typo?

Comment: Anyway, logging `document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')` on that page outputs all the canvas elements very well, not the first 18!

Comment: You really should post the code here, and not all of it; just the portion that exhibits the behavior you don't understand. It's odd that you're using jQuery and yet you also want to use the basic DOM routines too.

Comment: I did so. I did it from a tutorial. Wasn't thinking a lot about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `document.canvas` instead of your `canvas` variable. There is no such `document.canvas` collection maintained by the browser.

```
// remove---------v
var circle = /*document.*/canvas[index].getContext('2d');
```